# Exit and update nested nested elements in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm running into a basic problem with D3 and though I'm sure this has been answered, I can't seem to find the right keywords for it.

I have a simple data binding with nested elements which renders correctly, but when I try to remove elements, the nested elements duplicate because I am not clearing them correctly. What would be the proper way to clear nested elements?

```js
 var ul = d3.select("body")
    .append("ul")
 
 function update(data) {
  
  var lis = ul
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(data);
    
  lis.exit().remove()
  
  var newLis = lis  
    .enter()
    .append("li");

  lis.merge(newLis)
    .append("a")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .text(d => d)
    .on("click", removeItem);
    
  function removeItem(n) {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(n), 1);
    update(arr);
  }

 }

var arr = d3.range(5);

update(arr);
```

```css
body {
 font:  16px/145% sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Click any number to remove it

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is in:

```
lis.merge(newLis)
  .append("a")
```

You are merging the enter/update and appending.  You only want to append on the enter.  How about:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  Click any number to remove it

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var ul = d3.select("body")
      .append("ul")

    function update(data) {

      var lis = ul
        .selectAll("li")
        .data(data);

      lis.exit().remove()

      // enter
      var newLis = lis
        .enter()
        .append("li");
        
      // enter append the As 
      newLis
        .append("a")
        .attr("href", "#")
        .on("click", removeItem);

      // merge enter/update
      // select the as set text
      lis.merge(newLis)
        .select("a")
        .text(d => d)

      function removeItem(n) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(n), 1);
        update(arr);
      }

    }

    var arr = d3.range(5);

    update(arr);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```